# Open source fonts in LaTeX

Tags: fonts, copyright

Which LaTeX fonts are open source? Someone told me they are all, but I am not sure...

Comment: Note that TeX Live has a policy of only including 'free-as-in-license' material, so if the font is in TL you should be OK.

Comment: Are you sure you’re looking for *open source* and not for something like *with a liberal license*, e.g. the SIL Open Font License?

Comment: Unless you have some development ideas in mind, being open-source does not seem to be what you are looking for.

Comment: @JosephWright That's just not true. LPPL is certainly a licence, as is the GPL etc. In fact, TL has a policy of **not** including material with no clear licensing statement. (With the arguable exception of PD which is not exactly a licence.) What matters is the **content** of the licence. I spent a while trying to trace authors of older packages precisely in order to try to persuade them to **add** a licence so that their packages would not be removed from TL. Without a licence, nobody has any right to do anything with their code.

Comment: Some proprietary software companies have claimed that free software licences are not licences at all so that they are not legally bound to abide by their conditions. But that is a substantive and highly contentious legal claim which even those companies seem now to have abandoned. The GPL, for example, places restrictions on what you may do with material published under it. Their legal status depends on their being part of the licence so that your right to use the material is only as licensed. Perhaps you meant that TL's policy is to include only material published under a 'free licence'.

Comment: @cfr You misunderstand me: I mean 'license free' in contrast to 'cost free', not as in 'lacking a license'.

Comment: @JosephWright I did assume you meant something else but I find 'license free' misleading/confusing. I find it difficult to hear it as anything but 'licence-free'. It suggests to me that there are no restrictions on what may be done with the material but that's obviously false.

Comment: @cfr I've edited to 'free-as-in-license': is this clearer?

Comment: @JosephWright A little. I think it is much less misleading. While I don't find it obvious what it means, it doesn't suggest an erroneous meaning to me any more ;).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can check the li­cense for each and every font on CTAN. Go to the fonts section: [ctan.org/topic/font](http://ctan.org/topic/font), find the font you are interested in and check how it is [licensed](http://ctan.org/license/). If in doubt do consult the documentation! (Another good starting place is [The LaTeX Font Catalogue](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue). Just follow the links from there to CTAN.)

An example: The li­cense information for `EB Garamond` can be found under: [www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/ebgaramond](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/ebgaramond)

[image: EB Garamond information on CTAN]

(As cfr pointed out: always read the documentation carefully!)

Comment: Note that this isn't always enough. Sometimes you need to read the documentation e.g. some packages use one licence for the fonts and one for the support files. In those cases, the CTAN tag will just indicate something generic (e.g. 'other free') and you need to look further for details.

Comment: You are right: reading -- and especially understanding -- the documentation is advantageous.